# Href is not working on popup on Safari and mac browser

Tags: jquery, html

I have popup on my webpage on which I have `href` for another website, but it doesn't work in Safari browser and also on Mac OS.

#### HTML:

```
<p>
  <a  href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" onclick="javascript:parent.document.location.reload();">
    <span class="button-form" style="text-transform:none;">
      Proceed
    </span>
  </a>
</p>
```

Comment: Works on my mac in safari.  Opens in a tab, anyways.  You probably don't need the onclick.

Comment: mainstreetmark is right. You might want to write href="javascript:..."

Comment: @mainstreetmark: href="http://www.google.com" is for the link we want to navigate and onclick="javascript:parent.document.location.reload();" is to close the popup on parent page.